# meteor get no data from second mongo database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

iam total new at meteor and i try to build an Meteor application that should show the data another Mongo Database. The app it self can use its own metor database. So i found, that with `MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver()` its to connect with my second database.

Next step is to make it work in the meteor tutorial. But i dont get back any data from the second database. For a test, simple arrays are returned correct from my function and placed right into the webapp. And the expression in `.find()` should be also ok. I tested it in the Mongo console.

If the connection to the second database is placed in `if (Meteor.isClient)` or outside of the client/server parts, the error "ReferenceError: MongoInternals is not defined" appears. If its set inside of `if (Meteor.isServer)` sometimes an exception appears in the console:

> Exception in template helper: .`ris_sessions@http://localhost:3000`
>   /risdd_mongo.js?4fc7111851b4ed2182782e0a368b366cc4e89745:15:17
>   bindDataContext/<@`http://localhost:3000`/packages
>   /blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:2693:14
>   ...... and a lot more messages

I cant see, why dont getting back any data from the second database.

Here are the sources:

```js
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

//////////////////////
if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Template.body.helpers({
        tasks: function() {
          return Tasks.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1 }});
        }
        ,
        s_sessions: function() {
          return ris_sess.find( {},{description:1} ).fetch();
         
        }
    });
}


//////////////////////
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup

    var risdb_drv = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://172.0.0.1:27017/ris");
    var ris_sess = new Mongo.Collection("sessions", { _driver: risdb_drv });


    });
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>foo</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>todo list</h1>
            <!-- add a FORM !-->
            <form class="new-task">
                <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="ad your task here" />
            </form>
        </header>

        <ul>
                {{#each tasks}}
                    {{>task}}
                {{/each}}
                
                {{#each ris_sessions}}
                    {{>ris_session}}
                {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
    
</body>

<template name="task">
    <li>{{text}}</li>
</template>


<template name="ris_session">
    <li>{{description}}</li>
</template>
```

Comment: Maybe, the problem is another. After a couple of seconds the message comes up:

=> Started MongoDB.                           
I20141206-06:48:57.548(1)? Exception in callback of async function: Error: failed to connect to [172.0.0.1:27017]
I20141206-06:48:57.671(1)?     at null.<anonymous> (/home/row/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.0.8.qrjcjj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:536:74)

Comment: Did you find a solution - I am getting "MongoInternals is not defined" error too?

Answer (score 2):

If you use local MongoDB server try change

```
mongodb://172.0.0.1:27017/ris
```

to

```
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ris
```

Typo in IP: 127